# How to "decorate" textView (and classes that extend it) with new features?

Tags: android, fonts, decorator, textview, shadow

Since Android lacks some features on some of its views (like using a different font, or allowing to set the shadow using dp units), I had to extend each of the views i wanted and add some code to them, but since there are many, there is actually too much of the same code.

How can I achieve the minimal code writing for each of the views I wish to support, so that most of the code would be in a separate class?

Is it even possible to make the decorator to be attached to specific methods of its target view ?

Or maybe I should add instructions of how to use the decorator, and what functions to call on each method that I need to be attached to?

As an example of code, here's what I use for setting the font:

```
@Override
public void setTypeface(final Typeface tf, final int style) {
    if (isInEditMode()) {
        super.setTypeface(tf, style);
        return;
    }
if((style&Typeface.BOLD)!=0)
    super.setTypeface(FontLoader.getTypeFace(getContext(), FontType.ROBOTO_BOLD));
else 
    super.setTypeface(FontLoader.getTypeFace(getContext(), FontType.ROBOTO_LIGHT));
}
```

And about the shadow feature, I used [this link][1] together with the next code:

```
@Override
protected void drawableStateChanged() {
    super.drawableStateChanged();
    updateShadowColor();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this can help you, but I used the following code to be able to create a custom date display on a `Button` (so it should also be possible on a `TextView`):

```
String styledText = "" +
                "<font color='#000000'>" + month + "</font>.<font color='#ffffff'>" + day + "</font>" + 
                "<br />" + 
                "<small><font color='#666666'>" + year + "</font></small>";

Button dateBT = (Button) mi.getActionView();
dateBT.setText(Html.fromHtml(styledText));
```

It allows you to use HTML dynamically.

Comment: no, what i try to do is to have a general class that decorates any customized textview (including EditText,ToggleButton,Button,...) , allowing it to have (in my case) both shadow (using dp units) and setting of a custom font, while having the minimal code in each of the customized views.